# How do I call a function inside another function through onclick in my React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I have a function component which has an `outer()` function containing the `inner()` function. The `outer()` function returns the `inner()` function. When rendering the DOM, I'm attaching an `onClick` handler which needs to fire the `inner()` function but I'm not able to access it. How do I target it?

My code looks like this:

```
function Main() {
   ....
   function outer() {
      ...
      function inner() {
      ...
      }
   return inner;
   }
return (
   <button onclick={?}></button>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<button onClick={() => outer()()}></button>
```

or

```
<button onClick={outer()}></button>
```

Comment: Just a follow up, what if I have the outer function returning multiple functions like inner1 and inner2? How would I go on target inner2 for example?

Comment: how are you returning? in a array?

Comment: As an object { inner1, inner2 }

Comment: use object deconstruction `<button onClick={() => { const {inner1} = outer(); inner1()} }></button>`

Comment: fpr `inner2` use `<button onClick={() => { const {inner2} = outer(); inner2()} }></button>`